# Convert multiple rows into a single column

Tags: linux, command

Im trying to "convert" the following file from multiple rows into separated column.

classr#94   mesur#237   high#228    cash#232
classr#118  mesur#332   high#430    cash#421    Sar#380 
classr#57   mesur#89    hight#65

My desired output:

classr#94
mesur#237
high#228
cash#232
classr#118
mesur#332
high#430
cash#421
Sar#380 
classr#57
mesur#89
hight#65

I tried 
datamash -t: transpose < Filename but converted my file in very "weird" way

I also tried grep -o # File_name but i got only the #.

I think in the grep case if I find the way to get the entire word I will obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
cat filetoconvert | tr " " "\n"
```

Comment: It works perfectly , just a small correction  I added the \t as  I had a tab as separator so your answer should be  tr "\t " "\n"  !! But thank you very much.